# Cannot invoke equals on the primitive type boolean

Tags: java

```
    public boolean isChecked(Check check) {

    for (Measurement lookup : check.transcript) {
        if (lookup.getWidth().longEnough().equals(true)>3) {

        }

    }
```

Hey there I am looking to check if a width is long enough 3 times in my program however I cannot run this due to the error "Cannot invoke equals(boolean) on the primitive type boolean"

Am at a bit of a loss to why. Could it be due to .longEnough() having already returning a boolean value

```
    public boolean longEnough() {
    return this.lengthpass;
}
```

Comment: Simply compare with `==`

Comment: What do you mean by "long enough 3 times"?

Comment: I just noticed that `>3` in the condition. What is it meant to do? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `boolean` is a primitive type and for primitive types you use == instead of `equal`, secondly you don't need to compare to true or false and can simply write

```
 if (lookup.getWidth().longEnough()) {
```

or when chcecking for false use the negator operator !

```
if (!isChecked(someCheck)) {
```

---

A little off-topic but maybe the best way to write the longEnough method is like below

```
public boolean isLongEnough(int value) {
    return value > this.lengthpass;
}
```

Comment: `.longEnough() > 3` makes no sense if `longEnough()`returns a boolean.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I got mislead by the comparison to 3. I change back to my original answer